# Book on History of mathematics? (till current date)

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a book on history of mathematics that pays less attention on history and teaches you math(more attention), like when and how calculus was invented,what is calculus and where it is used, when and how number theory was discovered,what is number theory and where it is used, same about geometry,topology,combinatorics,analysis,concept of proof etc. (till current date)

Comment: This is exactly what you are looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Is_Mathematics%3F

Comment: In my experience, basically no history of mathematics books actually have history in them... concepts are treated Whiggishly and ahistorically to put the great march of Progress centre stage (which is complete crap, of course). /rant (I may have been educated to have a Pavlovian response here...)

Comment: Most books won't do what you are asking for. However, I have read a few books that come close to this. Here is the link to my folder of e-books (they should, at the very minimum, satisfy you for a short time). Happy hunting! https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1b5m7Wb07z_faWDWS_Yv1359n_bdIMEj7